# Can a vector hold different data types in two different occasions?

Tags: c++, vector

i want a single vector say `vector<userdefined> vec` to store some values. lets say i have created two objects B and C of class A.

Now i want object B to hold integers in my vector "vec" and object C to hold double in my vector "vec"

An example to illustrate this question

```
B.vec.pushback(int);
C.vec.pushback(double);
```

Can i create a template or use any overloading function to do that?

Comment: You want the same vector to hold different types?

Comment: In short no, it can't.

Comment: yes, is that theoretically possible?

Comment: @TMNT It's not possible, theoretically.

Comment: With C++ sky is the limit almost everything is possible. Alas, you can't in such a straightforward manner that you're showing.

Comment: Sure, you could accomplish this with a [variant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type).

Comment: If you're in the process of modifying `class A` then you could use templates to specify which type you want in the vector, by templating `class A`. Otherwise can't think of a straightforward solution.

Comment: I haven't used C++ in a while but can't you do this with generics?  aka have a class that holds a int and a class that holds a double and have the vector which is typed to use the parent class

Comment: You could use a straight up union if you really wanted to, but it would be like circumventing the language's type sytem.

Comment: I guess you can do this using `void*`,,,, this bad coding for me to contain deterrent types in vector

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting "why" you want to do this, you could store either `int`s or `double`s in the same vector by using unions.

```
#include <vector>

union userdefined
{
    int i;
    double d;
    userdefined(int p) : i(p) {}
    userdefined(double p) : d(p) {}
};


struct C
{
    std::vector<userdefined> vec;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;
    C A;
    C B;
    A.vec.emplace_back(i);
    B.vec.emplace_back(d);
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this. You should try to find a solution that doesn't require storing two types in the same data structure. It's too easy to access an inactive union member.